# Count views with Session

Tags: laravel

I'm new to laravel. I found a way here how to count article views, I used it on my own and it works as it should

```
$viewed = Session::get('viewed_article', []);
        if (!in_array($article->id, $viewed)) {
            $article->increment('views');
            Session::push('viewed_article', $article->id);
        }
```

But the only thing I do not fully understand is how it works and what it does, which makes me feel a little uneasy.

Who is not difficult, can you explain how this function works?

Comment: Read the documentation on Sessions: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#interacting-with-the-session. Note, this is using the `Session` facade, which is basically the same as `$request->session()` as noted in the documentation.

Comment: @TimLewis 
okay, i read it, thanks

Comment: No problem! If you're still unclear on what's happening, you can update your question with more details. Sidenote though, Stackoverflow is more of a QA site for specific coding issues, and not so much a "how does this code work" learning resource, so you might not get what you're looking for here.

Comment: @TimLewis I understand, that's why I wrote "who is not difficult", maybe there would be such a person)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line:

```php
$viewed = Session::get('viewed_article', []);
```

uses the `Session` facade to get the data with the key `viewed_article` from the session, or if nothing exists for that key, set `$viewed` to an empty array instead (the second argument sets the default value).

The next line, the `if` statement:

```php
if (!in_array($article->id, $viewed)) {
```

makes sure that the current article id is not in the `$viewed` array.

If this condition is true (i.e. the article is not in the array), then the views are incremented (i.e. increased by one) on the article:

```php
$article->increment('views');
```

Lastly, the article id is added into the `viewed_article` session data, so the next time the code runs, it won't count the view again:

```php
Session::push('viewed_article', $article->id);
```

Comment: thank you very much, the kindest person)